# Click specific text on a textView

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am working in a automation project for android application. Any idea on how to click specific text in a set of words in a textView?

The textView contains "By purchasing such item. Please be aware that there are certain guide or rules we need to read in order for the user to handle the product. The following link are Product Guide. Once you read the product please check out the terms and agreement."

I need to click Product guide and terms and agreement link, but the link has no indicator. So as of now I am using the coordinates of the text and I am working on one device. When switching to other device, the coordinates of the link is changed.

Comment: Have you tried by using `xpath` and text?  I'm assuming it's a separate `textview`

Comment: As of now I am currently using xpath for the textView, but there is no indicator on that specific text. I tried, FindElementByPartialText. It seems that the function is not supported by the version. Any ideas here mate?

Comment: Is there any way on how to get the coordinates of the specific text inside a textView?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the better solution: http://ezyautomation.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-clicktap-on-element-by-using-x.html

Comment: and could you please try by using this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Product guide']")).click();`